# Best practice to handle touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have simple click/touch listener:

```
$(document).off('click touchend', '.js-menu').on('click touchend', '.js-menu', function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        //do stuff
    });
```

It does work, but the trouble is, that when user is scrolling page on mobile, he is not expecting to click links/buttons.

So I'm trying to figure out the simpliest and best way or preventing occasional "clicks" on touchend event.

I've tried to google that stuff but there so much info on internet about touchevents so I couldnt find anything usefull.

Comment: What is the reason you want to handle the touchend event like this?

Comment: If this is to prevent the click delay in iOS devices, you should consider using  FastClick library instead of just treating touchend like a click, which is wrong.

Comment: `What is the reason you want to handle the touchend event like this?` How else would you handle touchevents?

Comment: `instead of just treating touchend like a click, which is wrong` - why is it wrong? How to handle touchevents without libraries?

Comment: Touchend is not a click. Browsers do not fire click event if the fingers have drifted but they do fire touchend event. But you handle it like they are the same. Thats not correct. And the reason for you to have to do so if what i am curious about.

Comment: During touchstart, save the touch coordinated. During touch end, calculate the deltas in X and Y using new touch coordinates. If they have not changed, apply your click handling logic.

Comment: Well, that's the only way it worked on iOs device under phonegap. I didnt realize that it's not a common way

Comment: `During touchstart, save the touch coordinated. During touch end, calculate the deltas in X and Y using new touch coordinates. If they have not changed, apply your click handling logic`
I did think about this, but Its kinda complicated - may be there a simplier way? I can think about one - set drag false on touchstart, and true on touchmove. And if it's true - do nothing on touchend.

Comment: That is why i asked you the purpose of this construct. If the purpose is to remove the touch delay, libraries like SwiftClick and FastClick are made to do so. Or, you can duplicate similar logic on your app and end up making the same library of your own with possible edge cases uncovered.

Comment: Well, I didnt know about 300 ms timeout on iOs - the problem that I'm trying to solve is about clicking occasionally while dragging..

Comment: I've used hammer.js library to handle the mobile events before. It already has predefined gestures, so you don't need to worry on saving initial coordinates before and after the action takes place. It has a pretty cool example on the gestures, and you can access it in mobile and see how it works. http://hammerjs.github.io/ give it a try.